# Nodegit - get diff between two commits

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nodegit

I have two branches `master` and `master.min` in my repo.

Suppose my current branch is `master.min`.

My master branch is at commit - `abcd`

Some pushes occur to master branch - `efgh`, `ijkl`

I store the current commit of my master branch:

```
 repo.getBranchCommit("master")
        .then(function(commit) {
            startCommit = commit;
        })
```

Due to high switching time between branches I need to do all the operations remaining on `master.min`

So, I do a fetch:

```
repo.fetch("master");
```

Now, I need to get the list of all the files which were added, modified or deleted between `abcd` & `ijkl`

```
commit.getDiff() is not enough. I need diff between two commits.
```

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for more clear answer:

```
const nodegit = require('nodegit');
const repo = await nodegit.Repository.open(repoDirectory);

const from = await repo.getCommit(fromCommitSHA);
const fromTree = await from.getTree();

const to = await repo.getCommit(toCommitSHA);
const toTree = await to.getTree();

const diff = await toTree.diff(fromTree);
const patches = await diff.patches();

for (const patch of patches) {
    console.log(patch.newFile().path());
}
```

Every patch represents a modified file and is an instance of `ConvenientPatch`. It has two methods `oldFile()` and `newFile()` which return an instance of `DiffFile` representing the file before and after modification.

NodeGit API docs:

- ConvenientPatch: https://www.nodegit.org/api/convenient_patch/
- DiffFile: https://www.nodegit.org/api/#DiffFile
- All API docs: https://www.nodegit.org/api/

Answer (score 3):

I need this too, but it seems is not supported by nodegit yet.

Having a look at https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/lib/commit.js#L196 I see the diff is calculated by comparing the commit tree and the parent tree:

```
return thisTree.diffWithOptions(parentTree, options)
```

So, I assume this could be achieved by implementing a variation of `commit#getDiff` that receives another commit's OID and calls `tree1 = this.getTree()` and `tree2 = getTheOtherCommit(OID).getTree()` and then invoke `tree1.diffWithOptions(tree2, options)`.

Of course the `getTheOtherCommit` is pseudocode but it's just to picture the idea.

As soon as I can I will try to implement it and post the progress here.

Comment: I ended up using git-promise wrapper  for git command to get diff. So my code uses nodegit as well as git

Comment: Very nice approach @jotadepicas. I implemented it and it works. It's not trivial because of the huge amount of Promises.